# What is the syntax for Operator Overloading in C++?

Tags: c++, class, operator-overloading, overloading

I was studying C++, and when I made a little program to learn more about **Operator Overloading** the program gives an erro in the main function where I wrote *"Ponto p1(1,5), p2(3,4), Soma;"*. Can anyone explain me how to use **Operator Overloagin** correctly? Thank you.

*PS: The program is in Portugueses, my native language, but I think that it will not be a problem to find my erro.*

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ponto
{
private:
    int x,y;
public:

    Ponto(int a, int b)
    {
       x = a;
       y = b;
    }
    Ponto operator+(Ponto p);
};

Ponto Ponto::operator+(Ponto p)
{
    int a, b;
    a = x + p.x;
    b = y + p.y;

    return Ponto(a, b);
}

int main(void)
{
    Ponto p1(1,5), p2(3,4), Soma; 
    Soma = p1.operator+(p2);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This has nothing to do with operator overloading. You don't have a default constructor, so you can't default-construct objects.

Comment: you should post the error you got

Comment: `Ponto` does not have a default-constructor (it is suppressed since `Ponto` declares its own constructor) but since `Soma` has no initializer it is default-initialized. This will cause a compilation error since there is no constructor taking 0 arguments declared in `Ponto`.

Comment: @Gabriel Mello, why don't you call the operator normally (Soma = p1+p2)?

Comment: Because I'm trying to learn how to use the Operator Overloading syntax by creating a simple code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a default constructor so when it tries to construct `Soma` you get an error.

Once you provide your own constructor the default one provided by the compiler is no longer generated.  You either have to make your own or add default values to the parameters on the constructor that takes parameters.

Comment: Thank God it is just the constructor and not the syntax of the Operator Overloading! Now it is working just fine, thank you for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should init `Ponto Some` in place with some value: `Ponto Some = p1 + p2;`

Also you should pass `"constant reference" - reference to const object`: `const Ponto &name` into the operator+.

#### So, fixed code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Ponto {
    int x, y;

public:
    Ponto(int, int);
    Ponto operator+(const Ponto&);
};

Ponto::Ponto(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {};  // Use 'initializer list'

Ponto Ponto::operator+(const Ponto &other) {
    // Not need to do calculations explicitly
    return Ponto(x+other.x, y+other.y);
}

int main() {
    Ponto p1(1, 5), p2(3, 4);
    // Not need to call operator+ explicitly - it's compiler's work
    Ponto Soma = p1 + p2;
    return 0;
}
```